# how to run multiple node surrealDB on docker

Tags: docker-compose, cluster-computing, surrealdb

I need a docker-compose.yml its like

```
version: '3'

services:
  node1:
    image: surrealdb_image
    container_name: node1
    volumes:
      - /path/to/node1/config:/etc/surreal
    networks:
      surreal_network:
        aliases:
          - node1
  node2:
    image: surrealdb_image
    container_name: node2
    volumes:
      - /path/to/node2/config:/etc/surreal
    networks:
      surreal_network:
        aliases:
          - node2  
  node3:
    image: surrealdb_image 
    container_name: node3   
     volumes :
       - /path/to/node3/config:/etc/surreal    
     networks :
       surreal_network : 
         aliases :
           - "node-3"

networks :
   surreal_network :
```

but its need to define also master node and ports then one line connection string

I asked chatgpt its give me above yml but it has missing part such as port

i just need a surrealdb cluster work on local docker